# Does an EEPROM consume power only during the transition edges or during entire read/write cycle?

Tags: power, digital-logic, energy, eeprom

Iam trying to simulate the loading behavior of an [EEPROM](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20002213B.pdf). It is powered by a 5V LDO.
When would the EEPROM actually consume power?

1. Does it consume power during the entire read/write cycle time? As per my basic understanding, digital ICs only consume power during state transitions. If so, shouldn't we be considering the sum of all rise/fall time for power calculation within a write cycle.

[image]

2. Why does [this source](https://www.electropages.com/blog/2016/02/using-mram-to-optimise-system-energy-consumption) refer to both rise time energy and write energy?
   [image]
   Disclaimer: Iam not a digital guy and know very little about the timing parameters.

Comment: Everything consumes power when statically operated. It may not be much, but, it's always present.

Comment: Think about it... why does a write cycle take so long?

Comment: @BruceAbbott: It takes multiple clock cycles to complete a write operation (which might consists of many sub operations). Thats all I can infer from that

Answer (score 14):

Here is an example write current waveform from the [NXH5104 4 Mbit Serial SPI EEPROM](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NXH5104.pdf) datasheet.

[image]

In the table of 'Static characteristics' the *average* write supply current with 4 sectors active and 5 MHz SPI is specified as 1.1 mA at 1.2 V. In the trace we do see a continuous current draw of ~1.1 mA. However there are also large 4 large spikes not directly related to SPI bus activity. The total charge consumed during the write cycle is a combination of the continuous current plus these bursts (which presumably are caused by the actual erase/write operations).

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how to interpret the above diagram.

1. What does D4-D1 indicate?

2. Why are there periodic dips( momentary glitches) in D4, D3 waveform?

Comment: The traces aren't well labeled. D4-D2 are the (digital) SPI clock and data lines. In this time frame each SPI transaction is so short that it looks like a glitch. If expanded you would see the individual clock pulses and data bits. It seems that the eeprom is being polled at intervals of a few hundred us, to detect when the write is finished.

Answer (score 7):

1. Yes, the EEPROM datasheet says that it consumes max 1mA while constantly reading from it, and max 3mA during a write cycle which can last up to 5ms, it does not even matter if you write a single byte or full page, as internally the EEPROM has to power the internal voltage generators for the full read-erase-program cycle.
2. Digital signal transitions communicating with chip takes energy, and internal EEPROM erase-write cycle to store the data takes energy. Two completely different things.

Answer (score 5):

> digital ICs only consume power during state transitions

This is wrong in general. CMOS logic **gates** consume **most** of their power during transitions on **their** inputs. A EEPROM IC:

- may have components other than logic gates (e.g. charge pumps) which consume power differently
- has leakage currents in idle state which may or may not be significant
- may generate transitions internally (e.g. may have internal clock signals) without any changes on the IC pins